# How to find the argument dependance of an expression

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation, variable

Consider expressions such as

```
X := f[n[1]][n[3]] g[n[7], n[1923]]
```

I would like to construct a function that returns the list of $n$'s on which $X$ depends. I know that we can easily test whether $X$ depends on some given $n[i]$, but here I would like to find directly the list of such $n[i]$, without having to iterate up to 1923.

Do you have any ideas how to extract the dependance of such expressions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you mixed up implicit or explicit. But if you just want to get the explicit appearances, you can use `Cases[X, n[_], All]`, which returns `{n[1], n[3], n[7], n[1923]}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Also, do you understand why your function misses n[1] on f[n[1]][n[2]] for example ?

Comment: Use `Cases[X, n[__], All, Heads -> True]`.